# constantly check if the virtualbox is started or still booting up from a script

Tags: server, bash, virtualbox, scripts

I am writing a shell script to start a virtualbox (ubuntu). After the command I want to put a for loop to keep checking the status of virtualbox and the script comes out of the loop only after the ubuntu is fully started.
Something like

vboxmanage starvm Ubuntu

```
for (i= 0; i < 100; i++)
{
continue if (vbox is not on)
}
```

exit when vbox is fully on and execute the next command

Comment: Actually I want to know if there is any command from which we can check the status of the machine because after Ubuntu is booted, I want ssh connection to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) to query the state of a Virtual Machine. The following command will list all running virtual machines on your system:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

The output will show you the following information which you can then further parse in your script:

```
"name_of_machine" <UUID>
```

This will of course not tell you whether the guest OS had booted properly, or is ready to use. For such informations you may need to run a script on the guest starting after  boot to send it's running state to the host.

Comment: Yes you are right for that purpose we need to have a script inside the guest OS. They also suggest the same thing https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=50241.
Since my next command in the script is to ssh the guest OS after boot therefore I will check if I add it in the loop and continue untill connection is established to the guest os.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late to answer that question. but it might help others.
you can run the following command to get the state of your Virtual machine

```
VBoxManage list vms -l | grep -e Name: -e State
```

it will tell you all of the virtual machines along with their status.
run this command in your loop, check each machine status.

```
if( stopped || paused ) 
VBoxManage startvm VMNAME           //here VMNAME is variable containing name of your vm
else
//do nothing
```

do it for all your vms.
i hope it helps